# Hibernate: How to avoid evict/detach on children elements

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple ManyToOne relationship between `Address` and `Person` entities using Hibernate on an old JavaEE 5 project.

On the Person class:

```
@ManyToOne
@Cascade(value = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
private Address address;
```

I'm trying to duplicate one Person record without using `clone` methods of Java. So I'm retrieving it from the database, calling `evict()` on the Person entity to detach it from the session, resetting its ID and persisting.

Problem > `detached entity passed to persist: Address`

Why is evict also detaching the Address entity? How can I avoid that? I don't want to create another Address record, I want to use the already existing one that it's supposed to be attached to the session, since I'm not using Cascade.EVICT or Cascade.ALL on the ManyToOne relationship.

Meanwhile, I'm evicting the Person, reattaching the address (find by ID), and then calling the persist. It's working fine like that, just wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: Can you just remove the `CascadeType.PERSIST` attribute from `address`? Just don't persist an address when you persist a person.

Comment: or simply `merge` instead of `persist` the duplicated person